# How to modify form-group div class of ActiveField in YII2

Tags: yii2, active-form

i have template like this:

```
<div class="form-group form-file-upload form-file-multiple">
<input type="file" multiple="" class="inputFileHidden">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputFileVisible" placeholder="Single File">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-fab btn-round btn-primary">
            <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

i use yii2 framework and try to configure field input file,

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'file_name')->fileInput(); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I have try to search in internet, but only can change the div class from-group like this

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
'fieldConfig' => ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group invisible']],
 ]); ?>
```

Please help me,how i can add

```
<input type="file" multiple="" class="inputFileHidden">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control inputFileVisible" placeholder="Single File">
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-fab btn-round btn-primary">
        <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
    </button>
</span>
```

into one div form-group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use the client validation feature of active form than you don't have to use the `$form->field()` to generate inputs. You can use `yii\helpers\Html` instead of `yii\widgets\ActiveForm` to have better control over the generated html.

You can have template like this:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
echo Html::beginForm(
    ['controller/action'],
    'post',
    ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'] //if you want to upload file with post
); ?>
    <div class="form-group form-file-upload form-file-multiple">
        <?= Html::activeFileInput(
            $model,
            'file_name',
            ['class' => 'inputFileHidden', 'multiple' => '']
        ); ?>
        <div class="input-group">
            <?= Html::activeTextInput(
                $model,
                'file_name', 
                [
                    'class' => 'form-control inputFileVisible',
                    'placeholder' => 'Single File'
                ]
            ); ?>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-fab btn-round btn-primary">
                    <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>   
<?= Html::endForm(); ?>
```

You can use `Html::error()` and `Html::errorSummary()` for displaying errors. [See Html helper documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-html) for more info.

Another option is to implement own widget that would extend `yii\widgets\InputWidget`. You will implement the `run()` method and generate required html code there. Then you can use your widget for example as `$form->field(...)->widget(YourWidget::class)`.

[InputWidget documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-inputwidget).

Comment: thanks for your reply, that works, but now how i can get the validation?

Comment: The server side validation should still work fine. If you need client side validation you have to partially implement it by yourself. You can use `clientValidateAttribute()` method of validators to get the JS code for the field validation. [See docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#clientValidateAttribute()-detail). If you want client side validation for other fields and not the file input, then you can still use ActiveForm for other fields and use Html helper only for file input (skip `Html::beginForm` and `Html::endForm`)

Comment: my server side validation not works, the validation ignore file extension rule but not with the string length (max) rule,  but may be i will post  another question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 framework. To modify/add the **form-group classes** use the field property: `"options"`

```
$form->field($model, "username", [
  "options" => ["class" => "form-group some-custom-class"]
])->textInput(["autocomplete" => "off"])->label('<i class="icon-user"></i> USERNAME');
```